# bundle identifier build errors xamarin forms ios and ios extention projects

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, onesignal, visual-studio-mac

I have been trying to deploy this iOS app for 2 days from visual studio for mac and I have been getting an error stating.

**"Found conflicts between different versions of "System.Numerics" that could not be resolved.  The reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed."**

This has has changed from Numerics to system.net.http after i removed system.numerics.  When I cleaned the project, the error message would switch to warning messages.  I cleaned up most of the warning messages.

When I look at the build log this is the build error i actually see.

**error MT7006: The App Extension 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' has an invalid CFBundleIdentifier (com.my.app), it does not begin with the main app bundle's CFBundleIdentifier (com.my.app).**

I switched over to my windows machine to build the app, it found the same warnings with the version conflicts.  But the error it came back with is the **MT7006**.

Im leaning towards this is real error even on the mac and the other errors are false.

This leads to the question, my ios app and my extension have the same bundle identifier com.my.app, i have even checked the info.plist files in text editors to make sure they match and they do.  I have cleaned the project and nothing seems to resolve the situation.

Any guidance is most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your extension cannot have the same id as the main app.

Comment: When I change the bundle identifier to unique one, the error is that it cant find the provisioning profile.  Do i need to create a provision profile for the extension as well?

Comment: @ChampChris yes, and it can’t be random it must begin with app I’d, just it must have something after it.